# Is there a way to stop the Concordion test when there is no test data found

Tags: java, markdown, concordion

I'm using Concordion Markdown 'run each row in the table as an example' type framework in Data warehouse Testing. I have to search for data in Source table if data found meeting pre conditions then validate that data against the target table. i.e. if a record is in source table then I must see one or more records target table based on some rules.
So if there is no data found in source table then no point in checking the target table i.e test need to stop running that example or that row in that case. 
So my question is there a way to do this in Concordion Markdown 'run each row as an example' to skip a row if some condition is not met and move to the next row in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to provide a "clean" example so I can understand what you are trying to achieve? I would have thought you'd want to check that there is no matching data in the target if there is none in the source.

Are you asking for the target columns not to be marked up in green or red? I'm not sure that's possible. You could try throwing an exception, which should move on to the next row, but might check any assertions first.

Comment: Thanks Nigel.
Yes I could and both source value and target value will be null and test will pass but not guarantee the business rule is tested with valid data. If all my tests pass like this then don't really testing with valid data so I would like to stop the test and move on to the next row in table. So i would know there is not test data and can mock up some test data.

I too thought of throwing an exception but report looks bit messy, so checking if there is any better way.

Comment: How about adding a column to the table for "valid data found"? This could run an assertion which would only pass if valid data was found.